# Speed up content loading

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

I am using [WinForms Sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2) downloaded from microsoft website. The problem is, that the model loading time is quite long, using:

```
contentBuilder.Add(ModelPath, ModelName, null, "ModelProcessor");
contentManager.Load<Model>(ModelName);
```

even a simple model, such as a cube with no textures, takes 4+ seconds to load. Now, I am no expert on this, but is there anyway to decrease loading time?

---

**EDIT:**

I've gone thru the code and found out that calling `contentBuilder.Build();` ,which comes right after `contentBuilder.Add()` method takes up most of the time.

Comment: The ContentManager can be very slow when running in Debug mode. Do you get the same results when switching to Release mode?

Comment: Actually 3-4 seconds was in release mode, debug mode takes up to 6 seconds.

Comment: It's compiling the .fbx/x model files when you run it. If you use content loading in a Windows forms application, you can always make it a Background progress with Background Worker or similiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that adding all models to contentBuilder: `contentBuilder.Add(ModelPath, ModelName, null, "ModelProcessor");`, and when all models are added, calling `contentBuilder.Build();` and then looping thru all models and loading them `contentManager.Load(ModelName);` speeds things up. Before one model took around 3-4 seconds to load, this way 8 models took around 6 seconds to load, so it is a improvement but I still think this is a bit to much, but agan I am no expert on this matter.